# dropdown menu for asp.net website

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

I need a drop down menu for my asp.net website where I can have menu items as well as images. I need one like http://www.petcarerx.com/. If I keep mouse on any of menu item on blue bar ( Dogs, Cats, Other Pets, A drop down menu opens with menu items and some images. I want it to expand to full length horizontally. Please suggest me which control should I use?

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Comment: Asif, I've created a small demo, hope you will like it, see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12316154/1516616) below.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good experiences with the [Kendo UI menu by Telerik](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/menu/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

searching a little google, i stumbled upon this website:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/11/25/overlay-effect-menu/

have a great tutorial for a great kind of jquery drop down menu

Answer (score 0):

I use [Superfish](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Superfish) for this purpose.Multilevel and Image supported when slightly customize it.

Answer (score 0):

use telerik menu control...

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/menu/examples/functionality/templates/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A quick example for you:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">about</a>
        <div class="submenu">
            <div class="col1 border-right">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">about link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">about link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">about link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">about link 4</a></li>
                </ul>                                    
            </div>
            <div class="col2 border-right">
                <img src="http://www.funnycutepics.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/fan-pet-karma.jpg" / width="100" />
            </div>
            <div class="col3">
                <img src="http://www.funnycutepics.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/fan-pet-karma.jpg" / width="100" />
            </div>
        </div>            
    </li>
    ...
    ...
    ...
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("ul#menu li").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('a').next('.submenu').stop(true, true).slideToggle(300);
}, function(){
    $(this).find('a').next('.submenu').stop(true, true).slideToggle(200);
})​
```

**CSS:**

```
ul#menu { 
    width: 100%; 
    position: relative; 
    height: 30px; 
    background:#ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;        
}

ul#menu li { 
    display: block; 
    float: left; 
    height: 30px; 
    line-height: 30px;      
}

ul#menu li a { display: block; padding: 0 20px; }

.submenu {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0px;
   display: none;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;    
}

ul#menu li div.submenu ul li {
   float: none;
}

.col1, .col2, .col3 {
    width: 33%;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    float: left;
}

.col2, .col3 {
    text-align: center;
}

.border-right { border-right:1px solid #ccc; }
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/TXzkD/)

​